# Using callbacks instead of loops?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, time, timer, callback

A wise man once told me: "Dude, stop thinking loops, and start doing callbacks." - I've been stuck now for three days with this problem.

I tried to convert the loop using a callback, but it isn't clear to me what kind of callback I can use.  The problem is to make a figure, and in it to make a loop that does the following:

for X times do:

1. Show some insignificant text ('X') in the center of the figure for a few seconds.
2. Load a randomly selected image and place it in the figure's center for Y seconds.
3. Measure the response time of the userr. The response can be a specific key pressed (lets say F) or no response at all. If there was a response go back to A eventually.

I have already tried a bunch of stuff: Using pauses, using `get(figurehandle,'character');`, using timer, using `while tic(toc)<y seconnds`, and until now, nothing worked.

Any ideas?

A couple of versions of my code so far are: [without a timer](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q83Us8kpUKApliBNhuKyPdaWDc1DTwAUy8pMPfYqJjA/edit), [with a timer here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11FQOIAA6c9Szo5GdkPsXVyvxoHYUiR4L3cXBKHzi1QQ/edit).

Comment: and why is it that loops are bad?

Comment: I'm a wise man too, trust me (:-)): working code is better by far than elegant pages of non-working code.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with loops- @foampile , just that for my problem the combination of the loop with the timer is an obsticale.. if i start in side my loop a timer than it reaches the start(timer) again too fast.. and thats gives me an error.. I also tried holding it back with while tic(toc)<3, but it made other problems..

Comment: if I had a working function I would'nt even think to change the loops to callbacks but until now, nothing works good- @HighPerformanceMark